# Android Game Development and Garbage Collection

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I have a been working on a game for Android and debugging it on my N1.  The performance was patchy at first.  I then worked on cleaning up all allocations to prevent garbage collection.  This greatly improved things,  but I still saw some garbage collections occurring that caused very brief pauses in the animation.

After pulling my hair out for a while, I then noticed the process IDs that were doing garbage collection (GC_FOR_MALLOC) were not my process id.  The Process Ids belonged to "Android System" and android.process.acore (determined by using "Android System Info" app from the market).  The acore process was tied to a desktop widget called digital clock.  I uninstalled the widget and nearly made it through the entire game without any pauses.  There was one very brief pause for GC for "Android System".

Sorry for the long explanation, but now for my questions:

1. How is it that other games don't occasionally have pauses due to the system process's GC (something out of the developer's control)?
2. Along the lines of the first question, how can I deal with a different application causing GC that slows my process down and causes hiccups in my game?

I just feel like there is something I am missing since other games don't have this problem.

Thanks

Comment: If your app is that sensitive to the garbage collector, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: You might have better luck at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ for game dev specific questions.  I'm not sure there is an easy answer to this.  You can't prevent gc's, just minimize them.  2.3 includes concurrent gc, but that doesn't help you much if you want to target earlier platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you decrease the frame rate of your game?  Maybe it's using 100% of the CPU so anything else that consumes CPU is going to make it lag.  These devices are not nearly as fast as your average PC.  You could also look at reducing the CPU required to create each frame in order to keep the frame rate high enough to be smooth.

Comment: You nailed it exactly.  My game was using 100% cpu.  The biggest thing I did to fix that was change how the background was drawn to not process transparency( function below).  My CPU immediately dropped from there.  Once the CPU was not pegged, I never noticed garbage collection at all.

thx

Comment: A little late to the party, but I have a similar issue.  How do you actually use less than 100% CPU, other than simply sleeping at the end of each frame? And what tool are you using to measure CPU use? Also, isn't transparency/no transparency really a GPU user, not CPU? Thanks!

Comment: @TenFour04: Almost by definition, you use less CPU by making sure to do as little work as possible.  Sometimes that means using a different image format (alpha is expensive, particularly if you have a crappy GPU or none at all), sometimes it means storing a reference to stuff so you don't have to look it up every time...sometimes it means waiting til you know you have to do something before you do it.  The specifics vary, but it all boils down to "don't waste CPU cycles".  Oh, and sleeping is a good thing -- if done well, it keeps frame rates relatively steady.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static Bitmap GetNonTransparentBitmap(int Id) {
  // no transparency
  Drawable tmp = myContext.getResources().getDrawable(Id);

  Bitmap retval = Bitmap.createBitmap(tmp.getMinimumWidth(), tmp.getMinimumHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(retval);
  tmp.setBounds(0, 0, tmp.getMinimumWidth(), tmp.getMinimumHeight());
  tmp.draw(canvas);
  return retval;
 }
```